# How can I use the same "table stripes" code snippet on various Google Spreadsheets without copy-pasting?

Tags: google-sheets

I *think* maybe what I want is to publish it as an "Add-on", but the "Publish" dropdown in the code editor only lets me publish it "as a web app", and I have no idea what that means.

I don't need to publish this to the "Add-on Store" or anything. I just don't want to have to go through the same ridiculous Code gallery -> Get a stupid popup -> Code editor -> Find old project -> Code editor -> Copy -> Go to new project code editor -> Paste -> Refresh a dozen times -> Remember I need to manually run the "On open" trigger once for some reason -> Refresh again -> Now it finally works process every time I want to quickly stripe a table in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Conditional Formatting doesn't work for me because I would need to set it up by hand again for every sheet. I want a fast way of adding that functionality to a new spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

No need for scripts; you can use custom formatting! Try this instead:

1. Select all in your sheet
2. Go to `Format > Conditional Formatting`
3. Set a `Custom Formula` like `=MOD(ROW(), 2) = 1` with a background color and range you like. This makes odd numbered rows the color you chose.
4. To make even numbered rows colored, do `=MOD(ROW(), 2) = 0` instead

If you understand how modulo division works, you can see how to easily make every 7th row yellow, or every 3rd row have red text, or even both (the fizz buzz problem as custom formatting!)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd prefer to figure out how to do this with a script, since I have other scripts that I'd like to have easy access to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do *exactly* what you asked in the question. If you wish to use a code snippet in every document, but you do not wish to make an add-on, then you must copy and paste like you described. Yes, it's annoying.

If you're making *new* spreadsheets, I'd suggest that you create them by making a copy of an empty document which already contains your script. That'd be a bit less annoying, but it doesn't deliver your use case of styling existing sheets. Copy/paste "format only" between sheets might do this, but that's hacky at best.

Given all that, I think that you should try using the "Table Styles" add-on. It does much more than what you want, but you should be able to get table stripes by performing these steps:

- Install the [Table Styles](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-styles/miephfllckffagckloelhmnbefefbldl) add-on
- Color a few rows of an empty spreadsheet with the stripe colors you like
- Select a range which contains your stripes
- Select `Addons > Table Styles > Create Style from Selection`
- Name your style, choose whether to have your stripes apply to headers, etc in the Table Styles side-bar
- Hit `Next` and tweak your styles more, if you choose
- Hit `Save`

Then later on, you can do `Addons > Table Styles > Apply style to selection`

I really hope this helps and is close enough to your original intent.

Answer (score 0):

No need for script *nor* for Conditional Formatting. Select and click

Format > Alternating colours ...